# Problem with GDevelop IAP. I can't find the error to get an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, mobile, in-app-purchase

Good Morning,

I have created my app with Gdevelop and I see that when you buy an item, the first time the result is duplicated and if I try again the app freezes.

On iOS I can see the following error a lot of times:

```
> 00:48.851.916 Default Space Warhog (3570) Space
> Warhog    Default [CdvPurchase.Validator] DEBUG: Schedule validation:
> {"className":"Transaction","transactionId":"appstore.application","state":"approved","products":[{"id":"com.stilugames.jabaliespacial"}],"platform":"ios-appstore"}   
> 00:48.851.949 Default Space Warhog (3570) Space
> Warhog    Default [CdvPurchase] DEBUG: Calling callback: type=approved()
> name=#efee3d7b1bea62da4bf830ac52793314
> reason=adapterListener_receiptsUpdated_approved   
> 00:48.851.983 Default Space Warhog (3570) Space
> Warhog    Default [CdvPurchase] INFO: verify(Transaction) 
> 00:48.852.026 Error   Space Warhog
> (3570)    com.apple.WebKit    IPC 0x112064220 -
> Connection::dispatchIncomingMessages: IPC throttling was triggered
> (has 11'306 pending incoming messages, will only process 60 before
> yielding)  00:48.852.055  Error   Space Warhog
> (3570)    com.apple.WebKit    IPC 0x112064220 -
> Connection::dispatchIncomingMessages: first IPC message in queue is
> WebUserContentControllerProxy_DidPostMessage  
> 00:48.852.115 Default Space Warhog (3570) Space
> Warhog    Default [CdvPurchase.Validator] DEBUG: Schedule validation:
> {"className":"Transaction","transactionId":"appstore.application","state":"approved","products":[{"id":"com.stilugames.jabaliespacial"}],"platform":"ios-appstore"}   
> 00:48.852.156 Default Space Warhog (3570) Space
> Warhog    Default [CdvPurchase] DEBUG: Calling callback: type=approved()
> name=#efee3d7b1bea62da4bf830ac52793314
> reason=adapterListener_receiptsUpdated_approved   
> 00:48.852.190 Default Space Warhog (3570) Space
> Warhog    Default [CdvPurchase] INFO: verify(Transaction) 
> 00:48.852.223 Default Space Warhog (3570) Space
> Warhog    Default [CdvPurchase.Validator] DEBUG: Schedule validation:
> {"className":"Transaction","transactionId":"appstore.application","state":"approved","products":[{"id":"com.stilugames.jabaliespacial"}],"platform":"ios-appstore"}   
> 00:48.852.257 Default Space Warhog (3570) Space
> Warhog    Default [CdvPurchase] DEBUG: Calling callback: type=approved()
> name=#efee3d7b1bea62da4bf830ac52793314
> reason=adapterListener_receiptsUpdated_approved
```

I've been checking and it comes from this JS script the problem, but I don't understand where it is:

Code10 JS:

```
gdjs.evtsExt__InAppPurchase__WatchItemEvent.func(runtimeScene, "500monedas", "quinientos_paid", "approved", (typeof eventsFunctionContext !== 'undefined' ? eventsFunctionContext : undefined));
```

gdjs-evtsext_inapppurchase_watchitemevent-func:

```
store.when().approved((transaction) => {
    // If we're watching this event, call the callback.
    if (eventName === 'approved') {
        transactionCallback(transaction);
    }
    // Automatically verify the transaction on approved.
    transaction.verify();
```

It also connects to the Cordova-plugin-purchase store file.

I have a test app where the same error appears and it is configured like this in GDevelop:

[First Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS3wU.png)

[End Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlsmU.png)

If anyone can help me or if it has worked well for someone and I am doing something wrong, I would appreciate your help.